# Alternative to $addToSet to process elements in an array (instead of the array as a whole)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a  collection in MongoDB with documents which follow this pattern:

```
{
        "_id" : {
                "id" : "ID1",
                "type" : "TYPE1"
        },
        "attrs" : [
                {
                        "name" : "ATTR1",
                        "value" : "foo"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "ATTR2",
                        "type" : "bar"
                },
                ...
                {
                        "name" : "ATTRn",
                        "value" : "blabla"
                }
        ]
}
```

Each document in the collection represents an entity (with an unique ID and type) an a set of attributes. Each document can have a varible number of attributes, even belonging to the same type (i.e. two documents with the same `_id.type` could have different sets of attributes).

I would like to get the names of the attributes associated to a given type (actually, the union of the attribute sets). I'm trying with the following:

```
db.runCommand({aggregate: "col", pipeline: [ {$group: {_id: "$_id.type", attr: {$addToSet: "$attrs.name"}} }]})
```

Which results in:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "TYPE1",
                        "attr" : [
                                [
                                        "ATTR1",
                                        "ATTR2",
                                        "ATTR3"
                                ],
                                [
                                        "ATTR4",
                                        "ATTR5"
                                ]
                        ]
                },
                ...                    
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

The problem is that `$addToSet` doesn't process element by element when adding the elements of an array. Instead of that, it considers the whole array as a single element an at it. Thus, at the end what I get is an "array of arrays" while what I would like to have is something like this:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "TYPE1",
                        "attr" : [

                                    "ATTR1",
                                    "ATTR2",
                                    "ATTR3",                                 
                                    "ATTR4",
                                    "ATTR5"
                        ]
                },
                ...                    
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

How the above query should be reformulated in order to get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the `attrs` array before grouping:

```javascript
db.col.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$attrs'},
    {$group: {_id: "$_id.type", attr: {$addToSet: "$attrs.name"}} }
])
```

Output:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "TYPE1",
            "attr" : [ 
                "ATTRn", 
                "ATTR2", 
                "ATTR1"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The `$unwind` duplicates each doc, once per `attr` element.

Answer (score 1):

## Look again for Mongo v2.4 +

`$addToSet` combined with `$each` works perfectly for saving and updating when you want to add array items *only* if they don't already exist.

```
{ $addToSet: { <field>: { $each: [ <value1>, <value2> ... ] } } }
```

reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each